# Uisearchbar doesn't "like" black color

Tags: iphone, sdk, uisearchbar

I got a very weird problem. 
I got a `UISearchBar` bar that I want it to be black. 
I've set the style, tint color on Interface builder to black BUT it shows up grey on sim and actual device.

When I change the tint color on Interface builder to anything else (i.e red) if works perfectly well.

Tried to ditch (delete from Interface builder)  it and re-create it but nothing. 
Tried to set it on my code. Nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here's the deal... I had two segment controls on the same view with tint color darkgrey.
It seems that the interface builder was stuck o this color.

As soon as i changed the segment control color to black and ran the project, the search bar followed the segment control tint color.
I have then changed the tint color of the segment control back to darkgrey, and everything works great!

It took me a day to fix this and it wasn't even my fault...
anyhow all good...

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this rather than changing tint color in xib

```
searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; //(RGB Values)
```

[image]

Strange:
  I just created search bar and changed it's tint color to black through code(not using xib). but it works fine on my simulator and actual device.

Comment: I did! It just doesn't like black!!! It always returns grey when is set to anything that resembles black!!! If I set it in code to red it works ok!!!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
CGColorRef topColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.4 alpha:1].CGColor;
CGColorRef bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithBlack].CGColor;

UISearchBar *search = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 41)];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
[gradient setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor,(id)bottomColor, nil]];
[gradient setLocations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], nil]];
[gradient setFrame:search.bounds];
[[[search.subviews objectAtIndex:0] layer] addSublayer:gradient];
[self.view addSubview:search];
```

Comment: you have to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: I did. I ment it wouldn't give me a black searchbar tint!!! See my answer above to see what was my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 41)];
[blackView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UISearchBar *search = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:blackView.bounds];
[[search.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:blackView];
[blackView addSubview:search];
```

Comment: it works that way. however i do wonder why the simple tintColor or even style doesn't do the job!

Comment: however this obscures the cancel button when search bar is selected and active...